# selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException:

Tags: python, selenium

I want to selenium in python. But, it doesn’t work..

> selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Expected
>   browser binary location, but unable to find binary in default
>   location, no 'moz:firefoxOptions.binary' capability provided, and no
>   binary flag set on the command line

I have already installed geckodriver, but it doesn’t work. I don’t know how I can do.

*two ways:

1. mv that file into my directory (/usr/local/bin)

2. brew install geckodriver

Please help me!

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40208051/selenium-using-python-geckodriver-executable-needs-to-be-in-path

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selenium using Python - Geckodriver executable needs to be in PATH](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40208051/selenium-using-python-geckodriver-executable-needs-to-be-in-path)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use parameter: `executable_path =`  when calling the WebDriver.